# Only a specific row is editable in Kendo-Grid

Tags: html, angular6, kendo-grid

I'm working with angular 6, and I have a Kendo UI grid.

I have a case, if user chooses (copy action) of a row, it inserts a new row with same data in the grid.
What I want is, make the user able to edit **ONLY** the new row.

So one row at a time is editable. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, verifiable code sample that reproduces the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the cell click event and closing the row if the row index is not the copied row index.

```
public editClick({ dataItem, rowIndex, columnIndex }: any): void {
        if(rowIndex != this.copiedRowIndex){
          this.closeEditor(this.grid,rowIndex)
        }
    }

private closeEditor(grid: GridComponent, rowIndex: number = this.editedRowIndex): void {
        grid.closeRow(rowIndex);
    }
```